# What are my options when tackling a bug when I don't have the original project for web applications?

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, struts

Basically I'm the new guy and all I got was an old intranet to manage. Deal is, the last guy is way gone and there's no one to turn for help. So, bugs happen -currently one of the systems is not authenticating users after a massive internal restructuring process.

What I do know: It's probably a Struts framework, there's a Glassfish server, a Java class that does the authentication and a MySQL database. And people said the last guy used NetBeans. I found the WAR files for this particular project, but I'm not sure what I can do with them. I tried looking up the JSP files that are on the server.

The actual page directs users to `"/auth/index.jsp"` which has little code:

```
<%@ include file="../incs/tags.jsp" %>

<% response.sendRedirect("https://intranet2.ibc.com.br/servlet/br.com.ibc.seguranca.itr.AutenticaASP?pag=http://"+request.getServerName()+"/sipro/autentica.do"); %>
```

I noticed the include file at the top, which also doesn't do much:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
```

My question here is how should I approach this. I'm thinking about getting a book on the Structs Framework and learning about it, but I'm not sure if I can recreate the original project with the server files.

I'm also wondering about the `/sipro/autentica.do` reference in the index.jsp file, since it doesn't seem to exist anything as `autentica.do` anywhere.

Any leads or tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Really no version control to checkout the project from? Then I wish you good luck, and you should convince whoever is responsible for this to introduce it as soon as possible... If the old guy's development machine is still there, I'd try to see if his Netbeans project is still at hand, make a backup of that before touching anything, and then try to get everything in a debuggable state. Good luck!

Comment: ._. No version control. His old machine was wiped clean after he left by a new user. My job is to keep this legacy piece of computer magic working until they finish the new intranet (might take a few years). The good part is that my boss knows how impossible this task is...

Comment: that `/sipro/autentica.do` is just a part of the parameter to your servlet `br.com.ibc.seguranca.itr.AutenticaASP`. Try checking `web.xml` to identify which Java class does this path relate to and then if you have Java source, find that Java class to understand what exactly it is doing. I believe, actual logic should be there in that Servlet code, not in `sipro/autentica.do`

Comment: First, this is not Struts 2, it's the original Struts 1. "Not having the original project" isn't very helpful--if you have *no source at all* you're pretty much screwed if there's anything at all implemented in the Java layer.

Comment: Without source, what can you do?? Try some java decompiler and get the source code first. Then try to setup the project in any IDE, run it and check errors in console. Edit your question with errors, then and only we can help you... :(

Comment: Try to import project using the war file in eclipse. If you have source code, your luck will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the actual Java files were exported/compiled with the WAR, there is a good chance you can just extract the original WAR to get the base structure for the project. Then you could use that as your "base" for recreation of the actual IDE project (choose your flavor, as it shouldn't really matter).

Once you get it built back up, CHECK IT IN TO SOURCE CONTROL. I've had to do this with legacy applications before. If you are lucky, the source will also be exported. If not, best of luck to you sir.